# Jekyll Horizontal Nav Bar Troubles

Tags: css, sass, jekyll

I am attempting to make a horizontal navigation bar in a jekyll site. I am not sure if the CSS I am using is incorrect, or if it's not compiling correctly with Jekyll.

Here is my current approach:
- Make changes in _scss/_layout.css 
- Check the changes are there in _site/main.css (they are)
- Check for errors in jekyll serve console (don't see any)

When I look at my generated site and hit inspect, I don't see the CSS changes being applied.

Sass code in `_sass/_layout.scss`:

```
 ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }

 li {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }

 h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: 200;
 }

 header {
 background: $header;
 padding: 0px 15px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 50px 0 0;
 height: 50vh;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 }
```

Full repo for my site is here - https://github.com/ericadohring/groupdayout/ and help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Github pages isn't showing changes anymore because there is an error that prevents Jekyll to build your site.

In `_sass/_layout.scss` there is a property that is using an undefined variable:

```
header {
   background: $header;
   ...
}
```

To fix it just assign a value to it before using the variable, e.g.:

```
$header: #f0ad4e;
header {
   background: $header;
   ...
}
```

Now you will be able to work on your site and seeing the changes reflected in Github pages.

Comment: I fixed that and my css changes are still not being reflected. As a test, I tried setting the font-weight in h1 in _layout to 800. When I save, it is reflected in _site/main.css (without me directly editing it), but when I hit inspect in the browser, it's still the old value (400).

Comment: Try cleaniing the cache or waiting a moment so Github pages reflect changes